# Cancel previous call for autocomplete input field during typing using Rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to write an autocomplete search field. The RxJs code I have so far looks like

```
search$.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  filter(search => search.length > 2),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(d => this.doRemoteSearch(d)),
);
```

This works great, however, what will happen when we are still inside `this.doRemoteSearch(d)` waiting for the backend and `$search$` fires again and calls `this.doRemoteSearch(d)` again. Is there a way to cancel the previous one? Can this be done with RxJx?

Comment: That's what switchMap does: it cancels the subscription to the previous observable. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap

Comment: Ok, awesome, so its all taken care of :) Thnx!